# Beaten/whisked/whipped

Tags: synonyms

Let's say you are reading a cook book about how to make a cake. It says:

> the egg whites are **beaten/whisked/whipped** until they form soft peak.

Are they all the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the UK](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beat%20the%20cream%2Cwhip%20the%20eggs%2Cbeat%20the%20eggs%2Cwhip%20the%20cream&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeat%20the%20cream%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhip%20the%20eggs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeat%20the%20eggs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhip%20the%20cream%3B%2Cc0) we usually ***beat*** the **eggs** and ***whip*** the **cream**...

[image]

...but apparently you're just as likely to [***beat*** the **cream**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beat%20the%20cream%2Cwhip%20the%20eggs%2Cbeat%20the%20eggs%2Cwhip%20the%20cream&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeat%20the%20cream%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhip%20the%20eggs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeat%20the%20eggs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhip%20the%20cream%3B%2Cc0) in AmE today. Oddly though, if I specifically check for *egg **whites***, I find that nearly everyone (except *me!*) [prefers ***beat*** over ***whip*** and ***whisk***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beat%20the%20egg%20whites%2Cwhip%20the%20egg%20whites%2Cwhisk%20the%20egg%20whites&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeat%20the%20egg%20whites%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhip%20the%20egg%20whites%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhisk%20the%20egg%20whites%3B%2Cc0)...

[image]

Personally I'd tend to ***whip*** with a manual "agitator" and ***whisk*** with an electric jobbie, but that's not a very hard-and-fast distinction. I ***beat*** eggs to make ***scrambled*** eggs - which is about mixing the white and yolk together, since the idea of just eating scrambled egg whites (without yolks) sounds unappetising.

To me, *whisking* and *whipping* are much more vigorous / extended processes, intended to introduce *air* into the mixture. But those charts suggest I may be in something of a minority there.

Comment: In search of a somewhat definitive reference, I looked at my copy of Julia Child's **The Way to Cook** for her meringue recipe (which is, of course, made by vigorously beating/whisking/whipping egg whites). She used **beat** in the recipe.